# R: Defining a new continuous distribution function to use with Kolmogorov-Smirnov Test

Tags: r, kolmogorov-smirnov-test, function

I wish to run the Kolmogorov-Smirnov test on my data to determine how well it conforms to a specific continuous distribution function I have in mind.

If my understanding is correct, the Kolmogorov-Smirnov test can be performed in R with something along the lines of:

```
ks.test(my_data, "pweibull", shape=2, scale=1)
```

where in the case above `pweibull` is indicating a test against the *Weibull* function.

The issue I am having is that the function I want to test against (the BiPareto function defined [here](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1389128602002980) for what it's worth) is not a standard part of R best I can tell.  Is it possible to define one's own function with parameters in R that can be passed to `ks.test()`?

ie. so I can have a call like:

```
ks.test(my_data, "bipareto", alpha=a_param, beta=b_param, c=c_param, k=k_param)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The help on the ks.test function is explicit - you can supply a cdf as a function:

`Alternatively, y can be a character string naming a continuous (cumulative)` 
`distribution function, or such a function.`

The last bit is where it tells you that.

So you can make a function called `bipareto` (say) that computes the cdf, and use that in the call. But you don't have to put it in quotes.